# Create const Widget by extension methods flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I already know about extension methods. but how can i create a const widget from them.
For example, I want to create a const SizedBox quickly by calling number.height or number.width directly. but for now I can only return Widgets with the keyword new.

Comment: check how they do [this](https://pub.dev/packages/time#-usage)

Comment: @pskink Thanks. but my case is create some widget with const. this packages is not. and I think only way is use default constructor of widget :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not feasible.

Something like `2.height` cannot use constructors, and your only choice is to write `const SizedBox(height: 2)`

Comment: Yes. I think I should create a custom class for this :(

Answer (score 3):

```
extension emptySpace on num
{

SizedBox get height => SizedBox(height:toDouble());

SizedBox get width => SizedBox(width:toDouble());

}
```

Usage of this extension

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Column(children:[
           Text("Hello"),
           20.width,
           Text("World"),
           20.height
        ])
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Sizedbox on num {
SizedBox get sBH => SizedBox(height: toDouble());
SizedBox get sBW => SizedBox(width: toDouble());
}
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining it.